# Trying to use sort method on a list but doesn't work. I have included code that works with the sorted method but can't understand why it doesn't work

Tags: python, loops, sorting, for-loop, methods

```
#Trying to find largest even number
def highest_even(li):
    even = []
    for num in li:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            even.append(num)
    print(sorted(even)[-1])

highest_even([3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 22, 11])
```

Comment: Your code prints `22` for me, which is the highest even number in the list. What's the problem?

Comment: What's the highest even number in this list: `[31221, 666, 3, 77543, 33, 5, 19, 4]`? Did you sort the list to figure that out? Probably not. Then why are you sorting at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max`:

```
print(max(i for i in li if i % 2 == 0))
```

Comment: @KlausD. Edited

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Edited

Comment: You can use also i & 1 == 0 instead of if i % 2 == 0

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica, I don't think so, it gives 1 for 3 because 3 in binary is 11. & 1 takes the first digit in the right to evaluate if it is even or odd. 1 for odd and 0 for even.

Comment: @m0r7y run it on the numbers from one to ten, it always outputs 0

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica, print(max(i for i in li if i & 1 == 0))?

Comment: @m0r7y Oh i know what you mean now, that works but mine is more often